# React Native Context Function is 'not a function'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to import a function defined in a 'context' file so I can access the user data across the whole app easily.

When importing it, and calling it in my 'useEffect' however, it's claiming it isn't a function - when it clearly is.

For reference, here is the component which I'm calling the context function from:

```
import { Context } from '../context/authContext';

const LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const { checkSignedIn } = useContext(Context)

  useEffect(() => {
    checkSignedIn()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Here is the context file itself (in full):

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';
import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';

import { Magic } from '@magic-sdk/react-native';
const m = new Magic('API key');

const authReducer = (state, reducer) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'checkComplete':
      return { ...state, userDetails: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const checkSignedIn = dispatch => {
  return async () => {
    // Set variable which calls Magic to check if signed in
    const checkMagic = await m.user.isLoggedIn();
    // If user signed in, redirect to dashboard and save details in state
    if (checkMagic === true) {
      const { issuer, email } = await m.user.getMetaData();
      dispatch({
        type: 'checkComplete',
        payload: [issuer, email]
      });
      navigate('authorisedFlow');
    // If user not signed in, redirect to welcome page and set state as null
    }
    else {
      navigate('loginFlow');
      }
    };
  };

export const { Context, Provider } = createDataContext( authReducer, { checkSignedIn }, { userDetails: null } );
```

Here is the 'helper' function called 'createDataContext' which iterates over the dispatch and defines it without having to repeat create context code:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};

    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key].dispatch;
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  };

  return { Context, Provider }
};
```

I don't think the navigate helper is necessary to show here, but happy to put in if needed. It seems to be more of a problem with the function itself!

If anybody can point out what I'm doing wrong here it'd be much appreciated!

Please let me know if any of that is unclear.

Comment: But redux-actions are not subject to change ... why are passing to as a `Context.Provider` `value`

Comment: The issue is that your initial context value is undefined. Normally you just provide a basic object with the shape of what your context provides. You appear to be creating some home brewed redux solution though, and since all your context is dynamic it isn't immediately clear to me how you'd resolve this.

Comment: @Jon **Side Note** Your code will re-render all consumers every time the Provider re-renders because a new object is always created for value ... Solution: First create obj for value and then pass it...

Comment: Thanks Hend - please can you provide an example of how I’d fix it as an answer?

Comment: The principle behind the context here is to have a way of universally passing down dynamic state. I’m not averse to following a different pattern if there’s a better solution out there? How else can I use context to control my data and allow it to be accessed throughout my app?